# SQL Server select best available time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my time slots table which indicates the reserved time from `isReserved` column - 0 is not reserved. I have all the day minutes available in this table.

[image]

I need to select best available time based from the table.

**Example:**
If I need to book a 4 minutes job, then it should return the first available time, and when I need to book a 30 minutes job, then the query should not return the first available as there are not enough minutes available in that timeslot and return the next first available.

I am using sql server 2008 r2

With the following query
Select timeslot from jpcbtimeslots where timeslot > @starttime and timeslot<= @endtime and isreserved ='0'

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots](     
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
[BayID] [int] NULL,     
[TimeSlot] [datetime] NULL,     
[IsReserved] [int] NULL,  
CONSTRAINT [PK_JPCBTimeSlots] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (  [ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) 
ON [PRIMARY] 
GO 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AC3392 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AC79E2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (3, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200ACC032 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (4, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AD0682 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (5, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AD4CD2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (6, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AD9322 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (7, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200ADD972 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (8, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AE1FC2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (9, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AE6612 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (10, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AEAC62 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (11, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AEF2B2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (12, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AF3902 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (13, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AF7F52 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (14, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200AFC5A2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (15, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B00BF2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (16, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B05242 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (17, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B09892 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (18, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B0DEE2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (19, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B12532 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (20, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B16B82 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (21, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B1B1D2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (22, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B1F822 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (23, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B23E72 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (24, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B284C2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (25, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B2CB12 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (26, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B31162 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (27, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B357B2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (28, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B39E02 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (29, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B3E452 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (30, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B42AA2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (31, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B470F2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (32, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B4B742 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (33, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B4FD92 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (34, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B543E2 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (35, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B58A32 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (36, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B5D082 AS DateTime), 1) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (37, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B616D2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (38, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B65D22 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (39, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B6A372 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (40, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B6E9C2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (41, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B73012 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (42, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B77662 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (43, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B7BCB2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (44, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B80302 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (45, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B84952 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (46, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B88FA2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (47, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B8D5F2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (48, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B91C42 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (49, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B96292 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (50, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B9A8E2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (51, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200B9EF32 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (52, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BA3582 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (53, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BA7BD2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (54, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BAC222 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (55, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BB0872 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (56, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BB4EC2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (57, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BB9512 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (58, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BBDB62 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (59, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BC21B2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (60, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BC6802 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (61, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BCAE52 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (62, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BCF4A2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (63, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BD3AF2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (64, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BD8142 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (65, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BDC792 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (66, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BE0DE2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (67, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BE5432 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (68, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BE9A82 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (69, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BEE0D2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (70, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BF2722 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (71, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BF6D72 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (72, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BFB3C2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (73, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200BFFA12 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (74, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C04062 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (75, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C086B2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (76, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C0CD02 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (77, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C11352 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (78, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C159A2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (79, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C19FF2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (80, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C1E642 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (81, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C22C92 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (82, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C272E2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (83, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C2B932 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (84, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C2FF82 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (85, 1, CAST(0x0000A62200C345D2 AS DateTime), 0) INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] ([ID], [BayID], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved]) VALUES (50435, 35, CAST(0x0000A62300AC3392 AS DateTime), 0) 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] OFF /****** Object:  Default [DF_JPCBTimeSlots_IsReserved]    Script Date: 06/11/2016 17:59:00
    ******/ 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JPCBTimeSlots] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JPCBTimeSlots_IsReserved]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsReserved] 
GO
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EnQ85.png

Comment: This is not a free development service. What query have you tried? Also identify which database are you using.

Comment: i have edited question,still the following part is not clear "when i need to book 30 mins job then the query should not return the first available as there is no enough minutes available in that timestamp" ..Also please tag specific RDBMS you are using

Comment: this is an islands and gaps type problem. Perhaps start by reading this: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions. That's a very verbose table structure

Comment: What exactly are we supposed to do with that image? We can't copy/paste it to create a test table, we can't run queries against it, we can't use it for anything. How do we test the queries that aren't working for you using that image? Images are only useful for things that can't be explained any other way. If you want help with your query, post the DDL to create the table, and the DML that inserts the data, and then include the SQL you've written that isn't working for you so we have something to work with to try and help.

Comment: Your timeslots start at 57 seconds and 980 ms? That's quite an exotic choice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the the total lengths of the timeslots by using row_number to figure out the gaps and islands then use filtering based on that.

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #TimeSlots
    ([X] int, [ID] int, [BaylD] int, [TimeSlot] varchar(23), [IsReserved] int)
;

INSERT INTO #TimeSlots
    ([X], [ID], [BaylD], [TimeSlot], [IsReserved])
VALUES
    (10, 10, 1, '2016-06-11 10:35:57.980', 1),
    (11, 11, 1, '2016-06-11 10:36:57.980', 1),
    (12, 12, 1, '2016-06-11 10:37:57.980', 0),
    (13, 13, 1, '2016-06-11 10:38:57.980', 0),
    (14, 14, 1, '2016-06-11 10:39:57.980', 1),
    (15, 15, 1, '2016-06-11 10:40:57.980', 1),
    (16, 16, 1, '2016-06-11 10:41:57.980', 0),
    (17, 17, 1, '2016-06-11 10:42:57.980', 0),
    (18, 18, 1, '2016-06-11 10:43:57.980', 0),
    (19, 19, 1, '2016-06-11 10:44:57.980', 0),
    (20, 20, 1, '2016-06-11 10:45:57.980', 0),
    (21, 21, 1, '2016-06-11 10:46:57.980', 0),
    (22, 22, 1, '2016-06-11 10:47:57.980', 0),
    (23, 23, 1, '2016-06-11 10:48:57.980', 0),
    (24, 24, 1, '2016-06-11 10:49:57.980', 0),
    (25, 25, 1, '2016-06-11 10:50:57.980', 0),
    (26, 26, 1, '2016-06-11 10:51:57.980', 1),
    (27, 27, 1, '2016-06-11 10:52:57.980', 1),
    (28, 28, 1, '2016-06-11 10:53:57.980', 1),
    (29, 29, 1, '2016-06-11 10:54:57.980', 1),
    (30, 30, 1, '2016-06-11 10:55:57.980', 0),
    (31, 31, 1, '2016-06-11 10:56:57.980', 0),
    (32, 32, 1, '2016-06-11 10:57:57.980', 0),
    (33, 33, 1, '2016-06-11 10:58:57.980', 0),
    (34, 34, 1, '2016-06-11 10:59:57.980', 1),
    (35, 35, 1, '2016-06-11 11:00:57.980', 1),
    (36, 36, 1, '2016-06-11 11:01:57.980', 1),
    (37, 37, 1, '2016-06-11 11:02:57.980', 0),
    (38, 38, 1, '2016-06-11 11:03:57.980', 0),
    (39, 39, 1, '2016-06-11 11:04:57.980', 0)
;
```

I added few more free slots to make the SQL return more rows.

The query:

```
select min(TimeSlot), max(TimeSlot), datediff(minute, min(TimeSlot), max(TimeSlot)) from (
    select row_number() over (order by TimeSlot) as RN1, row_number() over (partition by IsReserved order by TimeSlot) as RN2, * from #TimeSlots
) X where IsReserved = 0
group by RN1 - RN2
```

Returned data:

```
Start                      End                        Duration
2016-06-11 10:37:57.980    2016-06-11 10:38:57.980    1
2016-06-11 10:41:57.980    2016-06-11 10:50:57.980    9
2016-06-11 10:55:57.980    2016-06-11 10:58:57.980    3
2016-06-11 11:02:57.980    2016-06-11 11:04:57.980    2
```

This of course shows the free slots, so you'll need to add 1 minute to the duration

Answer (score 1):

Lets first create a temp table and fill it with some test data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tmpTimeSlots (ID int, TimeSlot datetime, IsReserved int);

INSERT INTO #tmpTimeSlots (ID, TimeSlot, IsReserved) VALUES 
(10,'2016-06-11 10:35:00',1),(11,'2016-06-11 10:36:00',1),(12,'2016-06-11 10:37:00',0),
(13,'2016-06-11 10:38:00',0),(14,'2016-06-11 10:39:00',1),(15,'2016-06-11 10:40:00',1),
(16,'2016-06-11 10:41:00',0),(17,'2016-06-11 10:42:00',0),(18,'2016-06-11 10:43:00',0),
(19,'2016-06-11 10:44:00',0),(20,'2016-06-11 10:45:00',0),(21,'2016-06-11 10:46:00',0),
(22,'2016-06-11 10:47:00',0),(23,'2016-06-11 10:48:00',0),(24,'2016-06-11 10:49:00',0),
(25,'2016-06-11 10:50:00',0),(26,'2016-06-11 10:51:00',1),(27,'2016-06-11 10:52:00',1),
(28,'2016-06-11 10:53:00',1),(29,'2016-06-11 10:54:00',1),(30,'2016-06-11 10:55:00',0),
(31,'2016-06-11 10:56:00',0),(32,'2016-06-11 10:57:00',0),(33,'2016-06-11 10:58:00',0),
(34,'2016-06-11 10:59:00',1),(35,'2016-06-11 11:00:00',1),(36,'2016-06-11 11:01:00',1),
(37,'2016-06-11 11:02:00',0),(38,'2016-06-11 11:03:00',0),(39,'2016-06-11 11:04:00',0);
```

This query should work on sql-server 2008.
Although I could only test it out on a more recent version.

```
WITH 
 Q1 AS (
   select TimeSlot as time, IsReserved as flag, row_number() over (order by TimeSlot) as rn 
   from #tmpTimeSlots
 ),
 Q2 AS (
   select t1.time as time1, coalesce(t2.time,getdate()) as time2, t1.flag as flag1, coalesce(t2.flag,-1) as flag2, 
     row_number() over (order by t1.time) as rn
   from Q1 t1
   left join Q1 t2 on (t1.rn = t2.rn-1)
   where t1.flag <> coalesce(t2.flag,-1)
)
select start_time, end_time, diff_minutes
from ( 
   select q1.time2 as start_time, q2.time1 as end_time, DATEDIFF(minute, q1.time2, q2.time1) as diff_minutes
   from Q2 q1
   join Q2 q2 on (q1.rn = q2.rn-1)
   where q1.flag2 = 0 and q2.flag1 = 0
) Q3
--where diff_minutes >= 4
--and start_time >= @starttime and end_time <= @endtime
order by start_time;
```

To criteria for the time range can be uncommented if that's required.

For the test data it will return these results:

```
start_time           end_time             diff_minutes
11.06.2016 10:37:00  11.06.2016 10:38:00  1
11.06.2016 10:41:00  11.06.2016 10:50:00  9
11.06.2016 10:55:00  11.06.2016 10:58:00  3
11.06.2016 11:02:00  11.06.2016 11:04:00  2
```

With Sql-server 2012 and beyond, the LEAD analytical function becomes available.
Which simplifies things a bit.

```
select start_time, end_time, DATEDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time) as diff_minutes
from 
(
  select dateadd(minute,1,time) as start_time, dateadd(minute,-1,next_time) as end_time
  from
  (
    select TimeSlot as time, IsReserved as flag, 
    LEAD(TimeSlot, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY IsReserved ORDER BY TimeSlot) as next_time
    from #tmpTimeSlots
  ) Q1
  where flag = 1 
) Q2
where start_time < coalesce(end_time,getdate())
--and DATEDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time) >= 4 
--and start_time >= @starttime and end_time <= @endtime
order by start_time;
```